# NiTE2 fails to initialize with .oni recording

Tags: kinect, openni

I've recorded some files with OpenNI2 Tools\NiViewer and I can load and read them with OpenNI2 without problems.
However, when initializing the NiTE2 nite::UserTracker it breaks on create() before it returns.

```
nite::Status et = nite::NiTE::initialize();
nite::UserTracker* m_pUserTracker = new nite::UserTracker();

if (m_pUserTracker->create(&device) != nite::STATUS_OK) {
    return openni::STATUS_ERROR;
}
```

The device was successfully created giving the path to the oni file and this exact code works if the stream is read directly from a kinect.
Is it necessary to give to NiTE more information about the .oni file before the initialization? Or NiTE2 doesn't support oni files?

Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!

Were you able to solve it?

please share the solution if yes

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately no, I still have to get up every time I need to test my applications. Did you get any solution? Thanks!